# Is it possible to animate a DIV's background color opacity?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, opacity

I have the following progress bar meter (below).

When I add the active class to one of the divs, I'd like the darker orange to animate from left to right. Is this possible with the current html/css structure?

```css
.progress-bar-item {
  opacity: .1;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.progress-bar-item.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar-item active"></div>
<div class="progress-bar-item"></div>
<div class="progress-bar-item"></div>
<div class="progress-bar-item"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There are several ways to do it, depending on your end goal. If you just want to animate within a given amount of time, then [CSS Animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) is your friend. If you want to animate in response to progress events, then you'll need to use JavaScript to change the width of an interior or overlaying element relative to your background element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple background. One for light orange and the other one for the dark orange by using a linear gradient. Then you change the size of the gradient so it goes above the light color when adding the `active` class. Like that you will create the left to right opacity animation (you can also make it for right to left or even consider top/bottom).

Here is an example (hover on the element to see the color change.

```css
.progress-bar-item {
  background:
  linear-gradient(to right,orange,orange) 0 0/0 100% no-repeat,
  rgba(255, 165, 0,0.1);
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition:.5s;
}

.progress-bar-item:hover {
  background-size:100% 100%,auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar-item"></div>
```

And here is an example where I add the class to all the items:

```js
var i = 0;
var update = function() {
  $('.progress-bar-item').eq(i).addClass('active');
  i++;
  if (i < 4)
    setTimeout(function() {
      update()
    }, 1000);
}
setTimeout(function() {
  update()
}, 1000);
```

```css
.progress-bar-item {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, orange, orange);
  background-color:rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.1);
  background-size:0 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.progress-bar-item.active {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar-item"></div>
<div class="progress-bar-item"></div>
<div class="progress-bar-item"></div>
<div class="progress-bar-item"></div>
```

Comment: this is amazing but I seem to be getting a build issue with "0/0" when I do a gulp build it is rendering like `    background: linear-gradient(to right,orange,orange) 0 NaN 100% no-repeat,rgba(255,165,0,.1);`

Comment: @AnnaSm make `0` to `0px` or `0%` instead, it will work i guess

Comment: strange, still compiling w NaN ... what is the 0/0 doing?

Comment: i can't get it working but I think this answers my question. My issue now is unrelated to the question so I'm accepting.

Comment: @AnnaSm the `/` is sperating two property ... am gonna update the code ;)

Comment: @AnnaSm check again my second code ... i split the property to use them separately and you won't have the `/`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the CSS `transition` property to animate the appearance of the active class like

```
.progress-bar-item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 2s all;
}
```

Here's an example that load the page, waits a second, add the class and fades the active class in over two seconds (Note that the jQuery is used here only to add the class).

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.active:last').next().addClass('active')
}, 1000)
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.active:last').next().addClass('active')
}, 2000)
```

```css
.progress-bar-item {
  opacity: .1;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.progress-bar-item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 2s all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar-item active"></div>
<div class="progress-bar-item"></div>
<div class="progress-bar-item"></div>
<div class="progress-bar-item"></div>
```

Comment: maybe it's me that i didn't understand, but he didn't say we want the transition from left to right of the color ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I read the question as asking to animate the opacity, going from left to right. OP has multiple step divs, which I believe they want to animate the opacity of. I see what you're saying in your answer, and if there was a single div that could work.

Comment: i made the work on only one div because i understand from this : *When I add the active class to **one** of the divs, I'd like the darker orange to animate from left to right. Is this possible with the current html/css structure*. So i thought he want the animation to work when you add the active class on a div .. maybe am wrong :) btw i added a complete example in my answer

Comment: Pretty sure for transition property markup you're suppose to order it `property animation-time easing delay` so while `2s all` might work it's technically improper markup.

Comment: @LeviSchmidt Nope, not improper at all. "zero, one, or two <time> values. The first value that can be parsed as a time is assigned to the transition-duration, and the second value that can be parsed as a time is assigned to transition-delay."  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: @j08691 so why does their documentation have it written (and nearly every where it's documented online) as `transition: margin-right 4s ease-in-out 1s;`?

Comment: @LeviSchmidt Probably because that's the order the spec lists the individual properties in. But as you can see, and as MDN shows, the browsers parse the values and don't rely on them being in an exact order.

Answer (score 0):

For any CSS property transition you'll was to use `transition` to achieve this. You can [consult the documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for a better explanation but you can simply add `transition: opacity .3s` to your base class and then any other modification (adding active) will result in a transition from .1 to your new opacity.